# how to rotate "Axis" from values and category in LineChart Java apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, linechart

Currently my diagram inside XLSX looks like this -> [Line diagram xlsx result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7xYl.png)

Unfortunately I need to switch the position between category and values to be looked like this -> [expected result line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWvmH.png) where I need to place values of the chart on the X-Axis and category on the Y-axis.

Are there any workaround or tipps how to rotate the position between these two axis in Java Apache POI?

I've tried to manage like this:

```
    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    chart.setTitleText("Test Line Chart");
    chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
    XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

    XDDFCategoryAxis leftAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setTitle("Test Category");
    XDDFValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    bottomAxis.setTitle("Test Values");
    bottomAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

    int firstRowNum = sheet.getFirstRowNum() + 1; //hier wird auch benötigt für Balken-component
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    XDDFLineChartData data = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, leftAxis, bottomAxis);
```

But lineChart still can't put category on X-Axis.

PS: I've also tried to use **AxisOrientation.MAX_MIN** for the categoryAxis, which at the end will be exported like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kSIJ.png)

How I add the data?

```
int indexColor = 0;
MutableInt mutableRow = new MutableInt(-1);
byte[] colorChart = vpsChartsXlsxDocumentExportService.setColorChart(colors.get(indexColor));
XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(colorChart));

String[] rawCategoryData = translationService.translate(language, null, chartData.getCaptions().toArray(new String[chartData.getCaptions().size()]));
BigDecimal[] rawValueData = chartData.getValues().get(0).toArray(new BigDecimal[chartData.getValues().get(0).size()]); //not only the first index from array

Row row = sheet.getRow(firstRowNum);
int cellValues = row.getLastCellNum() - 1;
int cellCategories = row.getFirstCellNum();

XDDFDataSource<String> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(
        (XSSFSheet) sheet,
        new CellRangeAddress(firstRowNum, lastRowNum, cellCategories, cellCategories));

final int numOfPoints = rawCategoryData.length;
final String valuesDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(mutableRow.intValue(), numOfPoints, cellValues, cellValues));
final XDDFNumericalDataSource<BigDecimal> valuesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(rawValueData, valuesDataRange, cellValues);

xddfLineChartData.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData);
chart.plot(xddfLineChartData);
XDDFChartData.Series series = xddfLineChartData.getSeries(0);
```

Comment: Are you creating the chart in the first place or is it coming form somewhere else?

Comment: yes I'm creating the chart in the first place @XtremeBaumer

Comment: Where are you adding the data? Something like `XDDFLineChartData.Series series1 = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(countries, area);` and `XDDFLineChartData data = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);` is missing from your code

Comment: I've added the corresponding lines how to add the data in my question @XtremeBaumer

Comment: Have you tried to swap `valuesData` and `categoriesData` in this line: `xddfLineChartData.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesData);`?

Comment: Yes I have tried to swap the data-contents between those two data, it still unfortunately exports the original result @XtremeBaumer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like apache does not support anything regarding "rotation" of chart area or switching the x- and y-values.
We ended up to use the original one (**ChartTypes.LINE**) like what we implemented till now.